# Быстрый нечеткий поиск по коллекции C#

Tags: c#, linq, коллекции, search

Предположим, есть коллекция вида `List<string>`, в ней очень большое число записей. Пользователь должен начинать вводить слово, а программа должна фильтровать список по введенным пользователем символам (от двух символов). То есть нужно быстро находить все значения из списка, которые содержат введенную пользователем подстроку. Можно это все фильтровать с помощью `Where` и `Contains` (или `IndexOf`), но есть мнение, что на больших размерах коллекции это будет работать не очень шустро.
Есть какой-то способ ускорить поиск?

Comment: для ускорения поиска нужно воспользоваться другой структурой данных

Comment: @Grundy, например? Мы ищем вхождение символов в строку, а не саму строку, hashset здесь не повлияет на скорость (а может и уменьшит даже)

Comment: Интересно, большой размер коллекции - это сколько? Может, имеет смысл это все в БД сложить и проиндексировать, или юзать что то типа Lucene?

Comment: преждевременная оптимизация - зло...

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать такую структуру: `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

При добавлении новой записи нужно выполнить такой код:

```
foreach (string substr in GetAllPossibleSubstrings(stringToByAdded))
    dictionary[substr].Add(stringToByAdded);
```

Где `GetAllPossibleSubstrings` ищет все возможные подстроки начиная с длины 2 (для вашего случая). В итоге поиск будет выполнятся за `O(1)`:

```
List<string> searchResults = dictionary[searchQuery];
```

Comment: Какой интересно будет размер у такого словаря ```на больших размерах коллекции```

Comment: Если ограничить длину подстрок каким-то разумным значением, то размер такого словаря будет расти линейно.

Comment: Разве количество подстрок линейно зависит от длины строки?

Comment: Количество подстрок длины `x` = `strlen - x + 1`. Если ограничить максимальную длину подстроки (например 5), получим количество подстрок приблизительно равно `4 * strlen`.

Comment: А, да, теперь понял вашу мысль. Но мы имеем N строк длиной M, то есть количество подстрок будет N*M*4, правильно?

Comment: Да, все правильно.

Comment: В любом случае, мне кажется ваше решение подойдет для небольшого количества недлинных строк, а если строк 1 000 000, и длиной они по 100 символов, то в память словарь не влезет.

Comment: Возможно, к сожалению автор не оставил деталей.

Comment: Ага, я уже запросил в комментах :)

Comment: А как быть с повторяющимися подстроками (ключами)?

Comment: Если автору нужно искать всего пару раз, то ресурсы затраченные на составление всех подстрок данной строки могут не окупиться

Comment: @Vlad, для этого значение по ключу это `List<string>`. @Андрей, если автору нужно искать пару раз, он бы не задавал такой вопрос.